# Cross-site associated question has been deleted

Tags: bug, site-crossover, russian-stackoverflow

The SO question [How to get current time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415511/3240681) has cross-site associated question on ruSO:

> [image: association]

The banner says: “this question has answers on Stack Overflow in Russian: ”.

Such banner only visible to users who have been detected by site as Russian-speaking.

In this case [target question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641030?fromen=415511) has been deleted, hence user without 10k reputation on ruSO will see a 404 page after clicking. This is not good behavior and I think algorithm for enabling the banner should be extended, in particular there should be a check that question has not been deleted.

Comment: How exactly does it detect that you are Russian speaking? (Or, how can I trick it into thinking I am Russian speaking?) I was able to find [the original Russian post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857), but it doesn't seem to explain this.

Comment: @Laurel I’m not sure, probably by Accept-Language HTTP header.

Comment: The question is not deleted now.

Comment: @Laurel as alex said, it depends on your browser's language settings. e.g. in Chrome you can access it in: chrome://settings/languages, add Russian, move to the top (you don't have to make it default) and you'll see that banner.

Comment: @ShadowWizard and ... do you recommend me to delete my question instead? :)

Comment: No, but maybe find a different example? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard to find another one when it be undeleted too? Nah :) the issue is described here, so I don’t see a reason to find different example.

Comment: @alexolut well, even just to know when the bug is fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think this bug will be never fixed, considered as extremly minor. :)